# What is the range for a demodulated AM signal?

Tags: modulation

Lets say I perform amplitude modulation (modulation index = 1) of a signal that has a range of [0, 1]. If I demodulate by taking the absolute value of this signal and then low-pass filter it, what will be the range of the demodulated signal (assuming the low-pass filter doesn't attenuate any of the modulation signal's frequencies)?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in the last parentheses. Not quite sure what you're asking us here.

Comment: Experimentally I seem to be getting a smaller signal back.